# Postgis Database: How can I get all gps points between specified timestamps and specified region?

Tags: postgresql, gps, range, postgis

I am totally new to DBMS. I have traces of vehicles in different csv files for each user. Format: name,timestamp,latitude,longitude,randomId. 
eg:user0,2008-10-2309:42:25,441972.694217,4428508.5117,2704942289

1) How to implement **RANGE Query** which asks for all the gps points of all vehicles seen between timestamp(t1) and t2 in range(center= lat,lon; radius=r km).

Since I have billions of lines in all csv. I created a basic table

```
  CREATE TABLE userDataBase1
(
    gid serial NOT NULL,
    name character varying(50),
    time_stamp TIMESTAMPTZ // postgresql doesn't have this datatype
    latitude numeric(12,8),// Don't know the data type for UTM points
    longitude numeric(12,8),
    pseudonym integer,
    the_geom geometry
);
```

Should I copy directly like this?

```
\copy landmarks(name,time_stamp,landmark,latitude,longitude) FROM '/local/path/to/Individual_Landmarks.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV HEADER;
```

2) what is the best way to copy and build database such that my **RANGE Query**(as defined above) returns data from billions of traces efficiently.

Atleast Basic implementation, which works is also fine.

Since I am new to DBMS. Explanation with small snippet is really helpful. Thank you so much!
P.S: I am using postgre 9.5, postgis 2.2, windows 10, pgAdmin III

FYI: I have connected successfully to database via Python script.

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="postgis_unistuttgart", user="postgres", password="vishnu", host="127.0.0.1", port="5432")
print "Opened database successfully"
```

Edit1:
Small change in the question. I have changed latitude and longitude to UTM cordinated like using python script.

```
import utm
import os
def gpsToUtm(latDeg,lonDeg):
    #print "gpsToUtm:",latDeg,lonDeg
    lat,lon,zoneNo,Zoneletter = utm.from_latlon(latDeg, lonDeg)    
    return lat,lon
```

Eg: Now i have position values like this (441972.694217,4428508.5117) in UTM.

1) What should be the datatype of UMT position(Meters) in the PostgreSQL Table ?
2) TIMESTAMPTZ is not available in my postgresql version. so what should be the correct data type for this format

> 2008-10-2309:42:25

.

Comment: Mmh...I think you should split you file in several small files - with say ten  millions lines - and import the data in several child tables using table inheritance. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-inherit.html. (I cannot post a answer since I not real experience in this task)

Comment: As you said.I reduced the number of lines from 4 years of data to month. Now I have less number of lines in different CSV files for each user. Can you please guide me with a snippet for implementing the RANGE Query? Thank you!

Comment: I don't know what a "RANGE Query" is, but a common index type used for spatial data is a [GiST index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GiST), which you can use with [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html). And if you need to mix geographic coordinates and metric distances, you may consider using the `geography` type.

Comment: @MikeT 
By range Query i mean " which asks the database for all the gps points of all vehicles seen between timestamp(t1) and t2 in range(center= lat,lon; radius=r km) "

Comment: @vishnu you can have the M-dimension for time. So either `geometry(PointM,4326)` or even `geometry(LineStringM,4326)`, with a GiST index would quickly find records in 2D space and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have billions of rows, use the [table inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-inherit.html) to speed up both the performance of your queries and the data loading process.

As said in comment, first split your input data in smaller dataset.
You first create a parent table and than so many child tables how you input files are. In the sample I used `landmarks_child_1` as table name. The other tables can be named i.e. `landmarks_child_2`, `landmarks_child_3` and so on.

```
-- Create a parent table landmarks
CREATE TABLE landmarks (
  id serial primary key,
  name text,
  time_stamp timestamp,
  landmark text,
  latitude double precision,
  longitude double precision,
  geom geometry(Point, 4326)
);
```

Now create and fill the child table landmarks_child_1. Repeat this step for all others child tables.

```
-- Create and fill the child table landmarks_child_1
CREATE TABLE landmarks_child_1 () INHERITS (landmarks);
ALTER TABLE landmarks_child_1 ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);   

-- create index for better performance.
CREATE INDEX landmarks_child_1_gist_geom ON landmarks_child_1 USING GIST (geom);        
CREATE INDEX landmarks_child_1_timestamp_index ON landmarks_child_1 ( time_stamp)


-- copy data
\copy landmarks_child_1(name,time_stamp,landmark,latitude,longitude) FROM '/local/path/to/Individual_Landmarks.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV HEADER;

-- create postgis geometries based on longitude and latitude
UPDATE landmarks_child_1 SET geom = St_SetSrid(ST_Point(longitude, latitude),4326);
```

If you have UTM coordinates instead of worldwide long/lag, just change the srid. I.e. in Bejiing you would use the srid [32650](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32650/)

```
UPDATE landmarks_child_1 SET geom = St_SetSrid(ST_Point(longitude, latitude),32650);
```

Now you have data in your database and can request data.

**Sample query**

In this sample query I request all points in a 100 meters radius around the coordinates 116.32015799999, 40.004775000971 (Beijin, China) and between the timestamps 2016-01-01 01:00:00 and 2016-01-01 02:00:00 (one hour).

```
SELECT * FROM landmarks 
WHERE ST_DWithin(geom::geography, ST_Point(116.32015799999, 40.004775000971)::geography, 100)
AND time_stamp BETWEEN '2016-01-01 01:00:00'::timestamp AND '2016-01-01 02:00:00'::timestamp;
```

If you have UTM coordinates, just use [ST_SetSrid()](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html) and don't cast to geography.

```
...
WHERE ST_DWithin(geom, ST_SetSrid(ST_Point(441972.694217,4428508.5117),32650), 100)
...
```

**Why inheritance?**

Primarily because of the better performance. If you have many millions of rows, your queries will be faster using inheritance as you would store one billion rows in a single table.
You can query the parent table and will have back results from all child table (according your WHERE clause).

You don't need to know in which child table your data physically are. Table inheritance will do this for you.  (for more info: see  [inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-inherit.html))

**IMPORTANT** The coordinates in Postgis are longitude/latitude, also x/y. In google map and the most map web api the coordinates are expressed in the reversed order: latitude/longitude (y/x). Use the right order!

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I have a small question regarding datatype declaration in TABLE. Now i have position values like this (441972.694217,4428508.5117) in UTM instead of gps.

1) Since position is in UTM i.e meters. can I go with same sample query ST_DWithin(geom::geography, ST_Point(13.1449583,52.5072111)::geography, 100)? you mentioned?
2) TIMESTAMPTZ is not available in my postgresql version. so what should be the correct data type for this format? or Should i go for timestamp without timezone ? my date+time formate is like this :2008-10-2309:42:25. Thank you so much.

Comment: 1) You need to know in which UTM zone your data are. See http://spatialreference.org. In which region/nation was token your data? 2) I use in my answer TIMESTAMP and not TIMESTAMPTZ.

Comment: I see now, your data was token in Stuttgart (Germany) but your sample  coordinates `441972.694217,4428508.5117` are not in Stuttgart. You probably made a error by trying converting them. Use directly the GPS coordinates, as PostgreSql support them.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am using [this Data of Beijing](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/b16d359d-d164-469e-9fd4-daa38f2b2e13/). These positions are given as input to kalman filter. So I thought Converting GPS to meters (UTM) would make my plotting and analyzing easy.Yes. I can  get the zone no(For this please view my code that I have writen in the question). Now will the Query WHERE ST_DWithin(geom::geography, ST_Point(13.1449583,52.5072111)::geography, 100) will change? Thank you.

Comment: You want to store in the database the coordinates as UTM, but your input for the query will also in UTM or in long/lat?

Comment: yes I want to store the coordinates as UTM in the database. input also in UTM. I am having a question now. Does it really matter if the positions stored in dabase and input has same units? Because later i will be using [simulated](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Networks/SUMO_Road_Networks) X Y Z points. Eg: x="11.583399" y="48.141984" z="515.497558". Do you see any problems?

Comment: See my answer, I added examples with UTM coordinates. You could store the coordinates in the database in other spatial references than the input coordinates. Than you would use the function ST_Transform() and reproject the coordinates on the fly, but the query would be slower.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have billions of rows, you would be better off to use a table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE userDataBase1
(
    gid serial NOT NULL,
    name character varying(50),
    pseudonym integer,
    the_geom geography
);
```

Note that the lat/long are available from the geography column, so there is no need to store them again as regular columns in the table.  To load the table, as suggested in the comments, you would batch loads into a table from which you would then load into the permanent table, like so:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE load_table
(
    name character varying(50),
    ts timestamptz,
    latitude numeric(12,8),
    longitude numeric(12,8)
);
\copy load_table FROM '/path/to/file' WITH CSV;
```

You would then copy the data from the 'load_table' into the permanent table using a query, such as:

```
INSERT INTO userDataBase1 (name, ts, the_geom) SELECT name, ts, st_setsrid(st_makepoint(longitude, latitude),4326)::geography FROM load_table;
```

Once the data is loaded, you would create a gist index to make lookups fast:

```
CREATE INDEX userDataBase1_the_geom_idx ON userDataBase1 USING GIST (the_geom);
```

With the data loaded and the index built, you can issue a query to extract out the records you're interested in:

```
SELECT * FROM userDataBase1 WHERE ts BETWEEN _timestamp1_ and _timestamp2_ AND st_dwithin(st_setsrid(st_makepoint(_longitutde_, _latitude_), 4326)::geography, the_geom), _meters_);
```

Note that this will use the geometry index and the expectation is that the results are sufficiently constrained thanks to that index that it's acceptable to simply scan all records within the area for those which meet the timestamp criteria.  If the timestamp portion of the query is highly selective on the table then a standard btree index could be created on the timestamp column using:

```
CREATE INDEX userDataBase1_ts_idx ON userDataBase1 (ts);
```

PostgreSQL would then choose which of the indexes to use (or, possibly, both, with a Bitmap Index scan) based on statistical analysis of the table and the specific values passed into the query.